# What are the top journals that focus on or cover matter modeling?

Tags: reference-request, publishing

**What are the top journals that focus on or cover matter modeling?**

For context: I am a physicist, which is a small field, so I find it difficult to navigate the much-larger space of materials science and chemistry that much of the matter modeling work tends to get done.

Comment: Physics a small field? :D

Comment: Compared to chemistry, biology or materials science, yes. In my subfield (condensed matter) you could probably make a whole career out of publishing just in Phys. Rev. B/E/Letters.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to say that, many Condensed Matter Physicists, some of them GIANTS of matter modeling, have an overwhelming majority of their papers in PRL and PRB. Take D. Vanderbilt, for example. On another end, many giants of other methods publish almost completely in J. Chem. Phys. It's good to see what other outlets are available, especially as interdisciplinary work is more common now.

Comment: Apples and oranges. Physics is a huge field, which includes particle physics, materials physics, mathematical physics, electronics, magnetism, optics, mechanics, etc etc etc. There are hundreds or thousands of journals that cover various aspects of physics.

Comment: There is a new journal called "Matter" haha. But I think they are not focused on computation

Answer (score 4):

## Journal of Chemical Theory and Computation (JCTC)

- 2019 Impact Factor: 5.011
- 2019 Total Citations: 33,459

This a popular journal from the [American Chemical Society](https://pubs.acs.org/page/jctcce/about.html) (ACS) that focuses exclusively on *new* developments in electronic structure theory, molecular dynamics, and statistical mechanics; the journal doesn't accept papers "...that are straightforward applications of known methods". So this covers advances in theory and methods, but not just papers that happened to apply DFT.

## Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling (JCIM)

- 2019 Impact Factor: 4.549
- 2019 Total Citations: 19,075

Another [ACS journal](https://pubs.acs.org/page/jcisd8/about.html) which focuses on cheminformatics, applications of machine learning, computational interfaces, and chemical representations. You will find some electronic structure/MD papers here as well, but the emphasis of these papers will be different than those in JCTC.